# c# adding items to combo box from database

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, combobox, user-controls

I want to  populate a combo box with items from my database i did this:

```
 public partial class addAssoc : Window
{
    private libraryDBEntities1 context;
    public addAssoc()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        context = new libraryDBEntities1();
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource libraryDBEntities1ViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("libraryDBEntities1ViewSource")));
        // Load data by setting the CollectionViewSource.Source property:
        // libraryDBEntities1ViewSource.Source = [generic data source]

        var q = from b in context.textbooks
                select b.Title;


        foreach(var item in q){
            titleComboBox.Items.Add(item);

        }
    }
}
}
```

which seems like its partially working, i am able to hover over the items in combo box, and they get highlighted, but they don't have the text. What is the reason for this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using wpf

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="titleComboBox" Width="120" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Margin="3" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" DisplayMemberPath="Title" Grid.Column="1">
```

Comment: windows form? or wpf?

Comment: Is Title a string? Please show us the xaml of the combobox.

Comment: Yes title is a varchar, so a string, i guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding

```
ItemsSource={Binding}
```

you tell the ComboBox to use its DataContext as ItemsSource.

Remove this and try again. Further i recommend to read on [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Edit: Also remove

```
DisplayMemberPath='Title'
```

Comment: Thanks the xaml was the problem, i was trying to add the items by dragging-dropping the data sources from a model, which didn't work, and after that i was trying to add them manually to the databound(?) combobox with a foreach, and that wouldn't work, for whatever -microsoft- reasons. I am guessing that this should not be done? Anyway after adding a completely fresh combo box everything works, thanks to everyone =) thank you very much